# Is it appropriate to ignore IDE metadata in Organisation Repositories?

Tags: git, ignore

If you are working in an organisation repository where there are multiple contributors and also a different usage of IDE, is it good practice to gitignore files such as`.idea`, `*.code-workspace` etc? I would like to find some reputable source, but I have the feeling that such settings should be omitted as they reflect individual developers' settings. What is your view?

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear whether you mean that these files should be put into the project-specific `.gitignore` or in your personal Git settings.

Comment: I have slightly changed question to clarify it, but I meant the .gitignore file in the organisation repository (company-wide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it generally is appropriate to ignore IDE metadata. You don't usually want that in your code repository since it really has nothing to do with the project code.

Of course, situations vary and it may make sense for your team to do so. Git documentation won't make that call for you.